# Are notebooks with NVIDIA GPU usually Gaming notebooks?

Tags: gpu

I am planning to purchase a notebook to do some Machine Learning development and ideally would like to have NVIDIA GPUs so that I can use CUDA as well.

Doing a search of the best notebooks for this, I find that (almost) all of them are gaming notebooks. I have never been part of the gaming community, so my question is:

Are notebooks that are equipped with NVIDIA GPUs usually gaming notebooks?

Comment: If you're buying off the rack, then yes, it will likely be called as a gaming notebook. But that doesn't mean you have to be a gamer or that you'll even notice (unless you get an RoG like I have). It's just a marketing ploy for high performance laptops.

Comment: Laptop for serious GPU computing is pointless. You're paying a markup for portability, and getting at least 10 times slower machine for twice the price you'd pay for a DIY rig with a desktop GPU card. I'd rather assemble my own dual GPU rig for the same money

Comment: I am planning on doing embedded development of deep learning models. I suppose that for the training phase, I will be given a high performance desktop, but I need a notebook for both developing inference engines for embedded platforms and also normal everyday office work

Comment: Therefore, I think a good idea would be to get a PC with GPUs for my development (I plan to do some CUDA too) and also have the protability of a notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most notebooks with GPUs are gaming notebooks, however there are a few non-gaming that have them. You may want to take a look at the Asus Zenbook 434FL (https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX434FL/), it has a GPU but without the 'heft' which usually comes with them.